# Intersection of two Bessel functions

Tags: roots, bessel-functions, ratio

I am trying to find an analytical expression (exact or approximate) for the following expression:
$$
  J_{n_1}(\alpha_1 x)= J_{n_2}(\alpha_2 x)
$$
where $J_{n}(x)$ denotes a Bessel function, $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\mathbb{R}$. This problem boils down to find the intersection of two Bessel functions which can be seen as either finding the zeros of their difference or an expression for their ratio. I haven't seen anything close that in the literature. Can you please help me solve this or point out to a paper that could help me solving it please?
Thanks in advance!